Centered table width with left aligned text
I need to make a centered table with left aligned text, so i use  l  instead of  p . But when doing so, the table width can't be set with l{length} just like  p{length}, hence the table just ran off out of the page to the right. So how do i do left aligned, but still be able set the width of the column
Here's the code
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{caption}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|}
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
    txt&txt&txt&txt\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{label}
\end{table}


Have you tried the array package?

Yes, i'm using array package. Answering Stephen

Your table is centered in text block area, content in the table is left aligned in the first and the last column, in others is centered as you declared by column specifiers, What actually is your problem. The column specifiers c, l and r is not possible to prescribe width of column.

Since you say you're employing the array package, I suggest you use the w column type instead of l. For instance, to specify that the column should have usable width (say) 1in and that the column's contents should be left-aligned, you'd enter w{l}{1in}. Incidentally, I fail to understand the logic in the first sentence of your posting, "I need to make a centered table with left aligned text, so i use  l instead of  p". The contents of a p-type column are left-aligned by default.

Does this answer your question? How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft? or Fixed column-width table with text left-aligned in cells.

Oh yeah that works! Thanks cabohah
